# ggplot2 - Equal x-axis distances across faceted plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, facet, ggpubr

Assume three datasets (`A`, `B`, and `C`), each representing a data.frame with four columns. The data in each dataset are paired, with the first half of all rows representing state "*bf*", and the second half of all row representing the state "*after*". The number of rows in each dataset is different, with set `C` containing equal to or more rows than `A` and `B` together.

```
A = structure(list(marker = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a", "b", "c", "d"), value = c("0.962", "0.923", "0.921", "0.938", "0.949", "0.898", "0.811", "1", "0.967", "0.944", "0.946", "0.96", "0.889", "0.923", "0.864", "1"), metric = c("rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci"), treatment = c("b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after")), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
B = structure(list(marker = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b"), value = c("1", "0.967", "0.966", "0.962", "1", "1", "0.967", "0.965"), metric = c("rc", "rc", "ci", "ci", "rc", "rc", "ci", "ci"), treatment = c("b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "after", "after", "after", "after")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
C = structure(list(marker = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), value = c("0.944", "0.934", "0.947", "0.944", "0.949", "0.922", "0.909", "0.923", "0.958", "0.857", "0.9", "0.914", "0.944", "0.934", "0.947", "0.944", "0.949", "0.922", "0.909", "0.923", "0.958", "0.857", "0.9", "0.914"), metric = c("rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "rc", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci", "ci"), treatment = c("b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "b4", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after", "after")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Assume further that we wish to visualize the variability of column *value* between the different classes.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

Plot_A = ggplot(data=data.frame(A), aes(x=marker, y=as.numeric(value), group=treatment, color=metric)) +
    facet_grid(metric ~ .) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=treatment)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
          legend.position="none",
          axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
    ylab("")

Plot_B = ggplot(data=data.frame(B), aes(x=marker, y=as.numeric(value), group=treatment, color=metric)) +
    facet_grid(metric ~ .) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=treatment)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
          legend.position="none",
          axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
    ylab("")

Plot_C = ggplot(data=data.frame(C), aes(x=marker, y=as.numeric(value), group=treatment, color=metric)) +
    facet_grid(metric ~ .) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=treatment)) + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
          legend.position="bottom") + 
    xlab("Marker") +
    ylab("Value")
ggarrange(Plot_A, Plot_B, Plot_C, nrow=3,  ncol=1)
```

How can I ensure that the x-axis distances between the individual markers in both, plots A and B, are the same as in plot C?

This what I want to achieve (without having to edit the individual plot widths manually):

[image: Illustration of desired outcome]

Comment: I thought the patchwork package may help here. `(Plot_A | plot_spacer()) / (Plot_B | plot_spacer() | plot_spacer()) / Plot_C` gets something close to what you want, but the axis are not aligning perfectly. So not a solution... but posting it here, in case it helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this approach can help you. You can add `scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(C$marker))` to the `A` and `B` plots, so that you keep same levels across all plots. Here the code. Also you can create a independent vector for the levels in x-axis and use it directly as `vec=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f")` and then `scale_x_discrete(limits=vec)`. The key is fixing this element in all the required plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

Plot_A = ggplot(data=data.frame(A), aes(x=marker, y=as.numeric(value), group=treatment, color=metric)) +
  facet_grid(metric ~ .) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=treatment)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(C$marker))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
        legend.position="none",
        axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  ylab("")

Plot_B = ggplot(data=data.frame(B), aes(x=marker, y=as.numeric(value), group=treatment, color=metric)) +
  facet_grid(metric ~ .) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=treatment)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(C$marker))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
        legend.position="none",
        axis.title.x=element_blank()) +
  ylab("")

Plot_C = ggplot(data=data.frame(C), aes(x=marker, y=as.numeric(value), group=treatment, color=metric)) +
  facet_grid(metric ~ .) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=treatment)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=unique(C$marker))+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45, hjust=1),
        legend.position="bottom") + 
  xlab("Marker") +
  ylab("Value")

ggarrange(Plot_A, Plot_B, Plot_C, nrow=3,  ncol=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for. I extended my question with an image of the desired outcome.

Comment: @MichaelG I will check now!